# D3DXVECTOR3 Pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, directx-9

The idea is I want to have only one D3DXVECTOR3 but inside it I want to be more 2 D3DXVECTOR3 declarations.

```
                D3DXVECTOR3 DEAD
               /
D3DXVECTOR3 foo
               \ D3DXVECTOR3 BEEF
```

Would the correct approach be

```
D3DXVECTOR3 foo[1];
foo[0] = DEAD;
foo[1] = BEEF
```

but with that I'm just accessing foo members right?

Comment: why? A D3DXVECTOR3 is just a struct of 3 floats how do you want to put 2 structs of 3 floats into one struct of 3 floats? I also highly advise against storing pointers into the memory of the floats if that's where you're going. Just use the correct data structures. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: And no, whatever the case it's not ok to allocate one struct and try to access two.

Comment: You can create a std::vector of type D3DXVECTOR3 and push both of them in the same container

Comment: foo needs to be a pointer to 2 more D3DXVECTOR3's

Comment: Then do this: D3DXVECTOR3 *foo = new D3DXVECTOR3[2];

Comment: yeah ok but then how would I put DEAD and BEEF inside it? Normal [0] [1] ?

Comment: Ya but that's not how you should be doing it, though it will work